# JavaScript que exibe quantos meses semanas dias horas minutos segundos tem em x horas

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando montar um script que transforma uma quantidade x de horas em meses semanas dias horas minutos segundos

só que tem um problema todos scripts que achei retornam por ex c vc tem 1 semana ele retorna 1 semana 7 dias x horas e assim pro diante.

ele teria que arredondar ou aproximar. se for difícil somente os dias serve

o script que estou tentando utilizar é mais ou menos este

```
function calcula(){
    / Set the unit values in milliseconds.
    var msecPerMinute = 1000 * 60;
    var msecPerHour = msecPerMinute * 60;
    var msecPerDay = msecPerHour * 24;

    // Set a date and get the milliseconds
    var date = new Date('6/15/1990');
    var dateMsec = date.getTime();

    // Set the date to January 1, at midnight, of the specified year.
    date.setMonth(0);
    date.setDate(1);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Get the difference in milliseconds.
    var interval = dateMsec - date.getTime();

    // Calculate how many days the interval contains. Subtract that
    // many days from the interval to determine the remainder.
    var days = Math.floor(interval / msecPerDay );
    interval = interval - (days * msecPerDay );

    // Calculate the hours, minutes, and seconds.
    var hours = Math.floor(interval / msecPerHour );
    interval = interval - (hours * msecPerHour );

    var minutes = Math.floor(interval / msecPerMinute );
    interval = interval - (minutes * msecPerMinute );

    var seconds = Math.floor(interval / 1000 );

    // Display the result.
    document.write(days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds.");

    //Output: 164 days, 23 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds.

}
```

só que este script utiliza uma data para comparar a outra e não é isso que eu preciso pois meu sistema retorna um numero x de minutos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criei essa função pra te ajudar:

```
function calcula(valorInicio){
    //primeiro criei constantes para armazenar os valores dos tempos em MINUTOS. altere eles de acordo com sua necessidade
    const minutos = 1;
    const horas = 60; //minuto * 60
    const dias = 1440; //hora * 24
    const semanas = 10080; //dias * 7
    const meses = 302400; //semanas * 4
    const anos = 3628800; //meses * 12

    if (valorInicio > anos){//verifica se é maior que um ano
        var ano = Math.floor(valorInicio / anos); //cria a variável ano e armazena a quantidade de anos nela
        valorInicio = valorInicio - (anos * ano); //atualiza o valorInicio
    }else{
        var ano = 0; //se for menor que um ano, cria a variável ano e deixa zerada
    }

    //faz o mesmo para os meses
    if (valorInicio > meses){
        var mes = Math.floor(valorInicio / meses);
        valorInicio = valorInicio - (meses * mes);
    }else{
        var mes = 0;
    }

    //faz o mesmo para as semanas
    if (valorInicio > semanas){
        var semana = Math.floor(valorInicio / semanas);
        valorInicio = valorInicio - (semanas * semana);
    }else{
        var semana = 0;
    }

    //faz o mesmo para os dias
    if (valorInicio > dias){
        var dia = Math.floor(valorInicio / dias);
        valorInicio = valorInicio - (dias * dia);
    }else{
        var dia = 0;
    }

    //faz o mesmo para os horas
    if (valorInicio > horas){
        var hora = Math.floor(valorInicio / horas);
        valorInicio = valorInicio - (horas * hora);
    }else{
        var hora = 0;
    }


        var minuto = valorInicio; //o que sobra são minutos
alert('Anos: '+ano+' - Meses: '+mes+' - Semanas: '+semana+' - Dias: '+dia+' - Horas: '+hora+' - Minuto: '+minuto);      
        //os resultados são as variáveis criadas, adapte o código de acordo com sua necessidade
        }
```

Comment: o código deu certo pra o que voce queria?

Comment: meu valorinicial é em segundos entao teria que multiplicar ele por 60 correto ?

Comment: sim, você pode fazer as alterações nas constantes de acordo com suas necessidades. cria uma constante nova chamada segundos e faça o novo cálculo das constantes

Comment: obrigado fiz uma leve adaptação mas resolveu ^^